# How to set the scrollbar to bottom after JTextPane finish loading image?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane, jscrollbar

I'm making a chat room with a `JTextPane` with html function. Users are able to input html tag to show image on the screen. But I'm having a problem to keep the scrollbar at bottom. I already try to do

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
    }
});
```

but the scrollbar scroll down then scroll up again. It seems like the picture finish loading after the function been called. I also tried:

```
ClientScreen._chatMsgPane.setCaretPosition(_chatMsgPane.getDocument().getLength());
```

but the result are the same. Is there's any event will trigger after all image finish loading? Or is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: btw I also tried to call Thread.sleep(450); after setText(); but it work strangely. The screen will become messy if I type quickly and every time when I send message the scrollbar will scroll up and scroll down. I mean it work but not well.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe; you can access posted images via `URL`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513), to reproduce latency.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this on a JTextPane that is loading an image but [Smart Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/smart-scrolling/) might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

JComponent has a method named [scrollRectToVisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) which is designed to do this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int end = chatMsgPane.getDocument().getLength();
        try {
            chatMsgPane.scrollRectToVisible(chatMsgPane.modelToView(end));
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // Should never get here.
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not entirely sure how you are addng the image to the JTextPane, but if you are loading it yourself, you can load it in a different thread with `ImageIO.read` and then scroll to bottom when the read is finished;  or, if you want to show the image progressively, you can obtain an ImageReader from ImageIO, and pass your own listener to its `addIIOReadProgressListener` method.